# NavigationStack does not render if child view contains a conditional

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I am trying to use SwiftUI's new NavigationStack/NavigationLink pattern but am running into an issue if the view I am navigating to has a conditional render (just a simple if statement) in it, it does shows the yellow triangle error icon and does not render the child view. If I remove this conditional statement, the view renders fine and the navigation works correctly.

I am able to reproduce this with a minimal example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Thing: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    var description: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let things: [Thing] = [
        Thing(name: "Thing 1", description: "Something new"),
        Thing(name: "Thing 2"),
        Thing(name: "Thing 3", description: "Something blue")
    ]
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(things, id: \.self) { thing in
                    NavigationLink(value: thing) {
                        Text(thing.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Thing.self) { thing in
                DetailView(path: $path, thing: thing)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                Text(thing.id)
                Text(thing.name)
                if !thing.description.isEmpty {
                    Text(thing.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be with this block:

```
if !thing.description.isEmpty {
    Text(thing.description)
}
```

If I remove this, the navigation works correctly. With this simple if statement, the navigation will not render the child view.

This is reproducible using Xcode 15.2 with the simulator running iOS 17.2

Behavior with conditional:

[image: Behavior with conditional]

Without conditional:

[image: Behavior without conditional]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a piece of this puzzle that I am missing or misusing?

Comment: Why do you have a `NavigationStack` inside a `NavigationStack`? `DetailView` should not have a `NavigationStack`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I thought everything had to be wrapped into a `NavigationStack` in order to trace the `path`. This was a basic example with only 2 levels, but I just tried multiple levels with just one `NavigationStack` and everything is working as expected now. Thank you!! I learned something today.

Feel free to post this as answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiple `NavigationStack`. Ideally, you should use the `NavigationStack` on the parent/root view only. Try the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Thing: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
    var description: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let things: [Thing] = [
        Thing(name: "Thing 1", description: "Something new"),
        Thing(name: "Thing 2"),
        Thing(name: "Thing 3", description: "Something blue")
    ]
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(things, id: \.self) { thing in
                    NavigationLink(value: thing) {
                        Text(thing.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Thing.self) { thing in
                DetailView(path: $path, thing: thing)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(thing.id)
            Text(thing.name)
            if !thing.description.isEmpty {
                Text(thing.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more suggestion, which is out of scope of your question. But I see you are using `NavigationPath` as @State var in your parent view. As your child views need the path so you need to pass the `path` during view initialization each time.

I would suggest you to use `EnvironmentObject` so that you don't have to pass the `path` as argument each time. You can follow the [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) to know more.